# Multi Device Hybrid Apps - support for xxhdpi and xxxhdpi densities on Android

Tags: android, assets, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps CTP 2.0. In the project template, there are several placeholder splashscreens and icons for Android: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi densities. How can I get support for xxhdpi and xxxhdpi densities? I tried following:

1. Added files to `res/icons/android` (icon-144-xxhdpi.png) and `res/screens/android` (screen-xxhdpi.png)
2. Added icon specification to config.xml according to [Cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens)

The xxhdpi images are not present in the APK file after a build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Visual Studio does not support xxhdpi or xxxhdpi and therefore *xxhdpi.png images does make it to package (*.apk). VS CPT2.0 supports below listed resolution and you can see the complete list across different platforms here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757053.aspx#VisualAssets

Workaround to include xxhdpi or xxxhdpi resources to package:

1. Create the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps project or open any existing project.
2. Build the project
3. Go to bld\Debug\platforms\android\res
4. Add folder for xxhdpi or xxxhdpi res like

[image]

5. Build the project. Do not re-build.

Now all the resources present under **bld\Debug\platforms\android\res** will be add to package (*.apk)

Supported icon and screen resources in Visual Studio Multi-Device Hybrid Apps CTP 2.0:

- icon-36-ldpi.png
- icon-48-mdpi.png
- icon-72-hdpi.png
- icon-96-xhdpi.png
- icon-96-xhdpi.png
- screen-xhdpi-landscape.png
- screen-hdpi-landscape.png
- screen-mdpi-landscape.png
- screen-ldpi-landscape.png
- screen-xhdpi-portrait.png
- screen-hdpi-portrait.png
- screen-mdpi-portrait.png
- screen-ldpi-portrait.png

Comment: Can you please explain how android manifest can be used to achieve that? AFAIK it's not possible to specify any additional files to be included in the APK there. Should I use some kind of build step to copy additional images to drawables in bld folder? If so, then how to create such build step?

Comment: I have updated the answer with workaround steps to add xxhdpi or xxxhdpi resource to package.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I hope the support for extra high densities will be included in final release.

Comment: VS 2015 final edition: the xxhdpi and xxxhdpi folders / files are packaged in the apk but when I upload it to the play store, under "supported resolutions" it only lists up to xhpdi.
also, the splash screen on a 10" tablet is very blurry.