# How do we include high res android launch icons in Visual Studio Cordova?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, android-manifest, visual-studio-cordova

The Visual Studio 2013 Tools for Cordova currently includes placeholders for lower res launch icons up to 96 dpi. (Android)

How do we add the other standard high res sizes?
 - icon-144-xxhdpi.png
 - icon-192-xxxhdpi.png

I've tried dropping them in the folder with the others but they don't get included in the package

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already answered in SO Post [Multi Device Hybrid Apps - support for xxhdpi and xxxhdpi densities on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767545/multi-device-hybrid-apps-support-for-xxhdpi-and-xxxhdpi-densities-on-android/25774046#25774046)

Workaround to include xxhdpi or xxxhdpi resources to package:

1. Create the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps project or open any existing project.
2. Build the project
3. Go to bld\Debug\platforms\android\res
4. Add folder for xxhdpi or xxxhdpi res

Comment: It seems every time you switch between debug and release these folders get wiped.

In Visual Studio Tools for Cordova there's only one project type called "Blank App (Apache Cordova)" Where's the "Multi Device Hybrid App"?

Also please update the official documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757053.aspx#VisualAssets
Most of the android splash screen resolutions are incorrect. (both incorrect dimensions and incorrect portrait/landscape labelling).